# Are there ways to link dataset from access to excel with query without moving cell reference?

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010

in one of my work tasks, my responsibility is to extract data from a table in access and further manipulate it on excel.

Traditionally the access table is extracted with some VBA that has gotten buggy from time to time and I would like to have an alternative way to extract access data to excel that is reliable and automatic. My choice was to use the get data function from excel.

Unfortunately, that excel has some pre-existing formulas that reference that section of data. When the data is extracted using the function, cell reference shifted and it is really a great hassle to find which formula made reference to the section of those data

I wonder are there ways to do that can make my life easier? Thanks.

Comment: The get data function is basically PowerQuery. So you could try to use PowerQuery to further transform the resulting table to match with your references (e.g. it’s just one step to change the order of the columns). Or what do you mean by cell reference shifted? Might also be interesting to understand where this buggy behavior of your VBA code come from. Actually, this should be exactly kind of question for here.

Comment: The tricky part is I am not too sure how switching columns help. Say my table has 3 columns and initially a formula took reference to cell A2, but it now references D2.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. My meaning is if you use the ms access connector to load the table into Excel, as part of the ETL you can just change the order of columns the way you need, e.g. you can change the order so the column D from the Access table becomes column A. Also, if you share the VBA code and some details what’s not working, maybe can be sorted out. After all, this forum is supposed to focus on solving coding issues rather than explaining how to use certain functions